# EF and Linked Tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I think I am missing something simple here. I am getting the error:

> "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_FeatureTypes'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.FeatureTypeCodes'. The duplicate key value is (28).\r\nThe statement has been terminated"

I have a look-up / linked table of FeatureType - (Mountain, Lake, River, etc.) which is already populated with data and is defined as:

```
[Table("FeatureTypeCodes")]
public class FeatureTypeCode {
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)] 
    public int FeatureTypeCodeID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

This is linked to my place table / object like this:

```
[Table("Places")]
public class Place {
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int PlaceID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public FeatureTypeCode FeatureTypeCode { get; set; }
    public ICollection<PlaceCoordinate> PlaceCoordinates { get; set; }
}
```

Then I am loading them from the old database like this (it is part of my conversion code):

```
foreach (DataRow r in table.Rows) {
        int ftID = Convert.ToInt32(r["FeatureTypeId"]);
        Place temp = new Place {
                PlaceID = Convert.ToInt32(r["PlaceID"]),
                Name = r["PlaceName"].ToString(),
                FeatureTypeCode = featureTypeCodeRepository.FeatureTypeCodes.FirstOrDefault(o=>o.FeatureTypeCodeID == ftID)
            };
            places.Add(temp);
        }
```

The error is being generated when it tries to insert a new FeatureType object with the same ID as an existing object while saving a Place. My thought was that by loading FeatureType from the context it would not attempt to insert a new FeatureType on saving the Place object. I am obviously wrong on that, but is it something simple I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that  you use the same DBContext Object in your `featureTypeCodeRepository` and the `places.Add(temp);`. So I think that basically EF don't keep track of the FeatureTypeCodes becuse it's loaded by one context, and saved by another.

Comment: Thanks, that was it. I was using Ninject to instantiate these in my main program, but did not in my conversion application and made the mistake of creating a new context for each repository.

Answer (score 0):

While I think that Simon Edström is right (+1), you may also consider to expose the primitive foreign key field (something like `FeatureTypeId`?) in your `Place` class. Then you can simply set

```
FeatureTypeId = ftID;
```

If you're not sure whether the FK field value really exists in the `FeatureTypeCodes` table, you can query for its existence using the `featureTypeCodeRepository` even when it has a different context. Using `Any()` is the cheapest way to do that:

```
var exists = featureTypeCodeRepository.FeatureTypeCodes
                 .Any(o => o.FeatureTypeCodeID == ftID)
```

It is not uncommon to do this in entity framework. Relationships consisting of only a reference (like `Place.FeatureTypeCode`) are called *independent associations*, those with a reference and a primitive FK property *foreign key associations*. Julia Lerman in her book *DbContext* says

> unless you have a very
>   good reason not to expose the foreign key properties you will save yourself a lot of pain
>   by including them